# jQuery autosubmit on enter, request for improvements

Tags: jquery, user-interface, webforms

Just did this on-enter-submit the form jQuery script. Before you start flooding "Don't it allready do this?" - yes if you have an actual submit button it does.

But i'm using `<a>` tags styled as buttons to submit the form. Unless javascript is disabled a `<noscript>` will reveal an actual standard looking submitbutton.

It should handle the browsers default autocomplete feature, by temporarly disabling the auto-submit-on-enter if arrow keys up/down is pressed, which will walk up/down the autocomplete list.

If you see any caveats, or have ideas for improvement they would be much apreciated.

Here's the script

```
// Submit form if focus on inputfields and enter is pressed
// To handle autocomplete, we disable next enter if arrow up/down pressed and autocomplete is not turned off 
$('form input:text, form input:password').keyup(function(e){
  var arrowKeys = new Array(38, 40);
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
  if(key == 13){
      if($(this).data('entersubmit')) {
          e.preventDefault(); 
          $(this).closest('form').submit();
          return false;
      }
      $(this).data('entersubmit', true);
  } else if($.inArray(key, arrowKeys) > -1) {
      if($(this).attr('autocomplete') != 'off') {
          $(this).data('entersubmit', false);
      }
  }
})
.blur(function(){
    $(this).data('entersubmit', true);
}) 
.focus(function(){
    $(this).data('entersubmit', true);
});
```

Comment: I could probably omit the onFocus or onBlur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would shorten it down using [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and an object map, [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to eliminate the unneeded jQuery objects and [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), which is already normalized, and a shorter array syntax, like this:

```
$('form input:text, form input:password').bind({
  keyup: function(e){
    var arrowKeys = [38, 40];
    if(e.which == 13){
        if($.data(this, 'entersubmit')) {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
            return false;
        }
        $.data(this, 'entersubmit', true);
    } else if($.inArray(key, arrowKeys) > -1) {
        if($(this).attr('autocomplete') != 'off') {
            $.data(this, 'entersubmit', false);
        }
    }
  },
  blur: function() {
    $.data(this, 'entersubmit', true);
  },
  focus: function(){
    $.data(this, 'entersubmit', true);
  }
});
```

Also note you don't need both [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) *and* `return false`, retuning `false` calls both [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: I used e.which to start with, but somehow the arrow keys returned as 0 (zero) !?

Comment: @Phliplip - very odd, which browser?